# Detect the id of a sent mail

Tags: xmlhttprequest, gmail, gmail-api

I would like to detect the message-id of an email

sent from the gmail interface?

what are your proposals?

Thanks.

Comment: Please expect your context more clearly. And what have you tried so far to achieve it?

Comment: The SO proposal is that you investigate ways to perform your task and then do those tasks.  If you have trouble, post what you have tried and the SO collective will attempt to help you solve said problems.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to first list messages:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14f60b097be71757",
   "threadId": "14f60b097be71757"
  },
  {
   "id": "14f603ead78aff97",
   "threadId": "14f603ead78aff97"
  }, ...
```

Then, get the message you want, and just ask for the `Message-Id`-header:

```
format = metadata
metadataHeaders = Message-Id

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14f60b097be71757?format=metadata&metadataHeaders=Message-Id
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "id": "14f60b097be71757",
 "threadId": "14f60b097be71757",
 "labelIds": [
  "INBOX",
  "CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS",
  "UNREAD"
 ],
 "snippet": "Cool snippet...",
 "historyId": "545168",
 "internalDate": "1440436229000",
 "payload": {
  "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "Message-Id",
    "value": "<10342275.20150824171029.55db500501e9a7@example.com>" // Here it is!
   }
  ]
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 73995
}
```